# Can you have a hyperlink in a text field?

Tags: html

Can you have a text field with hyperlinks in it?

Comment: This is a really broad question, try being more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a in a rich text field, such as [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).

The `input` and `textarea` elements can only hold plain text and do not support hyperlinks.